# VBA -change color of changes with Excel linked to Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba

### I found some VBA scripts to change font color of changes in Excel. However they only work if the change is manual. I have an Excel that is linked to MS sharepoint and pulls in changes from sharepoint. The VBA does no work in for these pulled in changes.  Any ideas?  This is the code I am using:

```
 Dim oldString$, newString$

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
    newString = Target.Value
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Debug.Print "New text: " & newString
color_New_Text oldString, newString, Target
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A100")) Is Nothing Then
        oldString$ = Target.Value
        Debug.Print "Original text: " & oldString$
    End If
End Sub

Sub color_New_Text(ByVal oldString As String, ByVal newString As String, ByVal theCell As Range)
Dim oldLen&, newLen&, i&, k&
oldLen = Len(oldString)
newLen = Len(newString)

Debug.Print newString & ", " & oldString
For i = 1 To newLen
    If Mid(newString, i, 1) <> Mid(oldString, i, 1) Then
        Debug.Print "different"
        Debug.Print theCell.Characters(i, 1).Text
        If theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 5
        Else
            theCell.Characters(i, 1).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share the code you have at this point by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54098310/edit)ing your question.

Comment: I added the code I'm using. Works if I make changes in column A.  But if I use the same code with an Excel that was exported from sharepoint, the code will not worked (when linked).